# How do i select every last child of a specific class in a list

Tags: jquery

I have a div which contains a list of other div as messages, I want to select every last child of the div that has the same class.

here is my code:

```
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
```

All I want is to select every last child of class `"q"`.

Like this:

```
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The second paragraph.</p> - Selected
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p> - Selected
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p> - Selected
```

Please Help no matter if it can be done through css, jQuery or PHP snippet

Comment: Uh, there not 'last'.  Are all these in the same parent?

Comment: yes they all are in a parent div call messages and P with class Q is the second person while normal P is the first person

Comment: @HarrisJones Guess I cracked it. You need to do two selectors. Kindly check out my answer. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked. These are the two selectors.

```
$("p.q + p:not(p.q)").prev("p");
$("p.q:last");
```

Or as a single one:

```
$('p.q + :not(p.q)').prev().add('p.q:last');
```

Could be complicated, but worth a try:

```js
$(function () {
  $('p.q + :not(p.q)').prev().add('p.q:last').addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The second paragraph.</p>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fourth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p>The seventh paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The fifth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
<p class="q">The sixth paragraph.</p>
```